# Solving the heat equation gives constant solution

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

For the heat equation

$$u_t = 4 u_{xx}$$
$$u(x,0) = 1$$
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)$$
$$0 \leq x \leq 1$$

we know that the general solution for Neumann boundary conditions is

$$u(x,t) = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n e^{-(n \pi)^2 4t} \cos n \pi x$$

but substituting the initial condition we get

$$u(x,0) = 1 = \frac{A_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \cos n \pi x$$

But the Fourier cosine series of $1$ is just $1$, so $A_0 = 2$ and $A_i = 0$ for $i > 0$

Then $$u(x,t) = 1$$

The fact that the solution is just $1$ makes me think that I did something wrong

Comment: I mean, look at the heat equation. What does it tell you about how $u$ changes over time for the given initial conditions?

Comment: Check that the constant function $1$ satisfies the required conditions. It does, doesn't it?